# Using $_SESSION in a javascript function within the wordpress functions.php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, session

I'm having some trouble right now with wordpress and the functions.php file. For reference I'm using ninja forms and pop-up maker.

I have a bunch of buttons. When you click one button, it opens a modal where the user will enter in their contact information. That information is then stored and a success message is displayed with a link to the resource the user requested. Since I don't want the user to have to keep filling out information for every resource, I have a cookie stored. To make up for this, I am storing the user's information inside the `$_SESSION` variable, since I still want to know when the user clicked a resource link.

Because I am using ninja forms I am hooking into the `ninja_forms_after_submission` function and storing the session in there.

```
function register_session(){
  if(!session_id()){
    session_start();
  }
}
add_action('init','register_session',1);

add_action('ninja_forms_after_submission','test');
function test($form_data){
  // assume ive processed some data here
  // and $form_data['name'] / $form_data['email'] is valid
  register_session();
  $_SESSION['name'] = $form_data['name'];
  $_SESSION['email'] = $form_data['email'];
}
```

Cool. This works and I can echo out `$_SESSION` and see valid data. Now, since the user is clicking links, and I want to still capture the session, I am doing the following (underneath the code above, still in `functions.php`):

```
add_action('wp_footer','save_session',500);
function save_session(){
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function($,document,undefined){
    $(document).on('click','.pum-trigger',function(){
      var post = {};
      post['name'] = "<?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?>";
      post['email'] = "<?php echo $_SESSION['email']; ?>";
      post['action'] = 'get_resource';
      $.post(ajaxurl,post,function(response){
      });
    });
  }(jQuery,document))
</script>
<?php
}

add_action('wp_ajax_get_resource','get_resource');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_resource','get_resource');
function get_resource(){
  echo json_encode($_POST);
}
```

This code does work and triggers every time a user clicks on a resource link after the first form has been filled out.

The problem is, `$_SESSION['name']` and `$_SESSION['email']` do not load into the javascript function until after the user refreshes the page.

So if I enter the information `Name: Test`, `Email: test@test.com` into the first form that pops up, and I verify that `$_SESSION['name']` and `$_SESSION['email']` were saved (by printing it out in the ninja forms hook), then I click another link, the line: `echo json_encode($_POST);` only shows: `{"name" : "", "email" : ""}`

After **refreshing** the page, and clicking a link, `echo json_encode($_POST);` now shows: `{"name" : "test", "email" : "test@test.com"}`

The problem with this is that the user probably won't refresh the page on their own. Is there some way to have the value that is saved from the `test()` function  appear in the `save_session()` function without reloading the page? I've tried `global` variables, but that doesn't work either.

Any advice on how to set this up would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try checking the `$_SESSION` variable in your `get_resource()` function? If those values are available there, you don't even need to send `name` and `email` in that Ajax request.

Comment: @Mithc I almost want to delete my question now.. -_- that worked, its been a long day

Comment: No! Keep it for future reference, of course! :)